# Is there a system colors collection in GTK#?

Tags: .net, mono, gtk, gtk#

How can I get a multi-platform system colors collection in GTK# (like [System.Drawing.SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.aspx) in .NET)?

I want an equivalent to `System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control` and `System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing in GTK.

In gtk every widget has a style associated to it. Many widgets may have the same style attached. Styles and their association to widgets are defined in theme or user's RC file.

You can find a little more information there:

- http://ometer.com/gtk-colors.html
- http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/gtk-Resource-Files.html

Edit: Ah, I forgot to add, that you can get a Style of any widget with the `Style` property on them. That way you can reuse its configuration on your own custom drawn control, if that is what you want to do.